# How to find the second lowest number in a list in python

Tags: python, min

I wrote this code to find the second lowest number in a list, but I'm not getting the correct result. Can you show me what I did wrong ?

```
def second_lowest_number(list):
    
    the_minimum = min(list)
    new = []
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if list[i] > the_minimum:
            new.append(list[i])

    return min(new)
```

Comment: So what input values give you an incorrect response?

Comment: There is no variable "t" in your function so the for loop would not run

Comment: @ankitbatra22 thank you for your remarque. In fact, in my orginal code I named my list ' t' but when I wrote it here I have changed it to list so you can understand it, but I forgot changing len(t) with len(list). I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(sorted(the_list)[1])
```

I would think would work and would not be any slower than any other solution

generally just keep it simple

if it has duplicates just use a set

```
 print(sorted(set(the_list))[1])
```

note that the first solution will fail if there is only one item in the list, and the second solution will fail if all items in the list are the same value

Comment: In one single line :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your function is that there is no variable t so the for loop would not run. Also, "list" is an in-built python keyword so avoid using that as the parameter name. Here is the working version of your implementation:

```py
def seconde_lowest_number(arr):
    
    the_minimum = min(arr)
    new = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] > the_minimum:
            new.append(arr[i])

    return min(new)
```

although I would recommend just sorting the list and returning the 2nd index like so:

```py
def second_lowest_number(arr):
    arr.sort()
    return arr[1]
```

Comment: the sort idea won't work ! because if we have a list where the lowest number is  duplicated, the function will return the lowest number ( for example l= [ 1,1,3,4,6,7] here the second lowest number is 3 but your code will return 1).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have a typo in your for loop.
It needs to be like this

```
for i in range(len(list)):
```

But, I would like to say something to you.
**1.** Don't use built-in function name as your variable/list name. You can use `newlist` instead.

**2**. It's better to avoid using `range(len(listname))`.
You can try this instead

```
for i in list:
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what your input list looks like, if your list contains unique numbers (no repetition) you can do something like below

```
numbers = [3, 6, 1, 7, 8, 2]


def second_lowest_number(arr):
    arr.sort()
    return arr[1]
```

However, if your list contains duplicated numbers, you could try something like this

```
numbers = [3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 6]


def second_lowest_number(arr):
    arr.sort()
    for i in arr:
        if i > min(arr):
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in linear time, I think this might work:

```
def second_lowest_number(list):
    the_minimum = list[0]
    second_min = the_minimum
    flag = False
    for i in range(len(list)):
       if list[i] < the_minimum:
           second_min = the_minimum
           the_minimum = list[i]
       elif the_minimum == second_min and list[i] > the_minimum and flag == False:
           second_min = list[i]
           flag = True
       elif list[i] < second_min and list[i] != the_minimum:
           second_min = list[i]
    return second_min
print(second_lowest_number([-2,3,5,2,2,0,5,1,2,3,5,-1]))
```

Please don't use this as a final answer, I'm just trying to brainstorm and aid as best as I can. If someone found cases where this code fails please share with me.